# Backbone View says model is undefined?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

i'm trying to get my feet wet with Backbone, but I can't figure out what's wrong here:

```
var  ToDoApp = {
            model: Backbone.Model.extend({
                default:function(){
                    return {
                        task: '',
                        completed:false
                    }
                }
            }),
            collection: Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: this.model
            }),
            view: Backbone.View.extend({
                model: new this.model(),
                tagName: 'li'
            })
        }
console.log(new ToDoApp.model());
```

I get an 'undefined is not a function' on the model for the view. What's going on?
Also, does the view even need to have a model there? Sorry if that's a really basic question, I still don't quite understand fully how backbone works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
collection: Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: this.model
})
```

will be executed when you're building `ToDoApp` but `this` won't be `ToDoApp` at that time, `this` will probably be `window` and `window` won't have a `model` property. The result is that you're actually saying:

```
collection: Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: undefined
})
```

Similar problems happen here:

```
view: Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new this.model(),
    tagName: 'li'
})
```

The easiest thing to do is build `ToDoApp` piece by piece:

```
var ToDoApp = { };
ToDoApp.model = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
ToDoApp.collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ToDoApp.model
});
ToDoApp.view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li'
});
```

Then you'd create the model for you view instance when you create the view instance:

```
var model = new ToDoApp.model();
var view  = new ToDoApp.view({ model: model });
```

Also, using names like `ToDoApp.Model`, `ToDoApp.Collection`, and `ToDoApp.View` would be more common for your "classes".

Comment: Ah okay, so having everything contained in that one statement would be a bad idea then? I wanted to try and make the application without going out of that first object declaration.

Comment: Mostly. The specific problems for you are `ToDoApp.model` and `this` not being `ToDoApp` when you think it should be. You could move the `model = Backbone.Model.extend(...)` stuff outside the `ToDoApp` declaration but that's just hiding the problem.

Comment: Here is what i came up with :http://pastebin.com/t92rsGG2
What do you think of that? Would that be a good idea to use in a real world setting?

Comment: Why must it all be in one statement? I tend to put each piece in a separate file and let my deployment system mash 'em all together. You've also create three accidental globals, assumed that `#todo-container` will be in the DOM when your JavaScript is loading, your `viewAll` should be using `this.collection` instead of `this.model`, and you can say `this.collection.each(...)` instead of `_.each(this.collection.toArray(), ...)`. You should at least familiarize yourself with [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org).